# pip3 is in my path, but when I try to run it it fails

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, path, pycharm

I picked up on a project i was working on a few weeks ago. At the time pip worked with no issues. now i am getting an error when importing modules. i tried to do a pip3 freeze just to make sure everything was still installed but then i got this little gem of an error. pip3 is installed and is in the path, which finds it no problem. but when i try to run it i get an error.

```
(venv)  computername  ~/PycharmProjects/FS-Jware-Trading   mainline ±✚  which pip3  
/Users/username/PycharmProjects/FS-Jware-Trading/venv/bin/pip3
```

```
(venv)  computername  ~/PycharmProjects/FS-Jware-Trading   mainline ±✚  pip3 --help   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/FS-Jware-Trading/venv/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what happened but i just deleted the virtual environemtn and created a new one then reinstalled packages from my requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Install pip on cmd or terminal and try to run it from there.

Comment: Pip was installed the whole time i had ran
which pip3  
/Users/username/PycharmProjects/FS-Jware-Trading/venv/bin/pip3